# Multiple Queries in Wordpress Custom Post

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, alphabetical

I have 2 CPTs: Locations and People. **On each single location page,** I have a section displaying all the people who work at that location.

I'd like them to be organized by two fields:

- Staff group (a radio button with labels of #1-6)
- Last Name

I thought I found something to organize them by staff group, but it doesn't appear to be working on every page.

- Correct order (directors, therapists, assistants, custom service specialists/aides): https://aptw.nk-creative.com/location/goshen-ny/
- Incorrect order (the director is near the end): https://aptw.nk-creative.com/location/woodstock-ny/

```
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying single posts.
 */
?>

                <?php while (have_posts()):
    the_post(); ?>

                <?php
    /*
     *  Query posts for a relationship value.
     *  This method uses the meta_query LIKE to match the string "123" to the database value a:1:{i:0;s:3:"123";} (serialized array)
    */
    $staff = get_posts(
        array(
            'post_type' => 'people', 
            'posts_per_page' => - 1, 
            'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND', 

                'location_clause' => array(
                    'key' => 'location', // name of custom field
                    'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"', // matches exactly "123", not just 123. This prevents a match for "1234"
                    'compare' => 'LIKE',
                    ), 

                'order_clause' => array(
                    'key' => 'staff_group', 
                    'compare' => 'EXISTS'
                    )
            ), 
            'orderby' => array(
                'location_clause' => 'ASC', 
                'order_clause' => 'ASC')
                )
            );
?>
```

I am still in the early stages of learning custom WP, so any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things that stand out:

```
'posts_per_page' => - 1,
```

I don't think that space should be there between - and 1.

Also, rather than:

```
'location_clause' => array(
    'key' => 'location',
    'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"',
    'compare' => 'LIKE',
    ),
```

simplify this query with:

```
'location_clause' => array(
    'key' => 'location',
    'value' => get_the_ID(),
    ),
```

The default `compare` is '='.

Finally, you don't really need to:

```
'location_clause' => 'ASC',
```

because there should only be one value for location, right?

Otherwise, the query looks sound. So let's clean it up and see what we get :)

Comment: Suggestions #1 and 3 helped, but #2 (about simplifying) broke my pages... Perhaps I need that for ACF relationship field I use to assign people to a location. Unfortunately, I am still unable to sort within each category by last name.